# Nodemon error with mondoDB: " app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nodemon

Idk why this happen, i've  readed the code 5x and i cant see the mistake. (im used requireDir)

[image]

server.js code:

```
//chamando 
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const requireDir = require('require-dir');
//iniciando app
const app = express();

//iniciando o DB
mongoose.connect(
    "mongodb://localhost:27017/nodeapi",
    { useNewUrlParser: true }
);

requireDir('.src/models');

//first rote
app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    res.send('hello worlldd');
});

app.listen(3001); //porta

//NODEMON - LIVE 
/* "dev": "nodemon server.js" no package
npm run dev no terminal */
```

Product.js code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },

    description:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },

    url:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },

    createdAt:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
    },
});

mongoose.model('product', ProductSchema);
```

[image]

[image]

The server just dont run. Everything was normal before I put the "mongoose".

im used docker and robot3T too.

[image]

The whole error

[image]

Comment: Yeah so are you using any Authentication for your mongodb database? And also please post the whole error. Not just the `app crashed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provided path path to `requireDir()` has a typo. You are including the path `.src/models` instead of `./src/models`.

Fixed `server.js`:

```
//chamando 
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const requireDir = require('require-dir');
//iniciando app
const app = express();

//iniciando o DB
mongoose.connect(
    "mongodb://localhost:27017/nodeapi",
    { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }
);

requireDir('./src/models');

//first rote
app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    res.send('hello worlldd');
});

app.listen(3001); //porta

//NODEMON - LIVE 
/* "dev": "nodemon server.js" no package
npm run dev no terminal */
```

Comment: Thanks man.

It was exactly that, what a silly mistake. I'm starting to study mongo and node now, I made a silly mistake.

Comment: **for people with the same error, is that it appears in the terminal:** 
`
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
(node:2140) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
`
**And the "http://localhost:3001/" open normally**

Comment: In order to fix this warning message, include the `{ useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }` as the configuration options on `mongoose.connect`.

Comment: Thanks man, its always good to see a brazillian friend right here. Unfortunately in the Brazilian forum nobody answers.

Comment: Do you know the [Rocketseat community](https://rocketseat.com.br/comunidade)? There is a lot of developers in their Discord channel helping each other and the main language is portuguese. Also, they share a lot of useful content about Javascript. Have a look later, I strongly recommend you.

Comment: yeah, im studying in skylab, but i never used their discord before